# Spring boot actuator not working when deployed as war to jboss

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am able to get actuator to work while running from eclipse using

> http://localhost:9876/health

but when I package and deploy it to jboss 7.1 as war

> http://localhost:8080/apps/myapp/health

does not work.

I am using springBootVersion = '1.5.1.RELEASE'

Relevant files given below

Boot config and servlet initializers

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.myapp")
public class Application {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args
     *            the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer#
     * configure(org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder)
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.child(MyExceptionMapper.class);
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }    
}
```

AppConfig class for custom bean loading

```
@Configuration
@Import({ 
    EndpointAutoConfiguration.class, 
    PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
    HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AppConfig { beans...}
```

Application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

The context path of the app is set using jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/apps/myapp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Exclude JAX-RS: 2. re-import the javaee.api and exclude the JAX-RS 
                classes -->
            <module name="javaee.api">
                <imports>
                    <exclude-set>
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs" />
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs/core" />
                        <path name="javax/ws/rs/ext" />
                        <path name="javax/validation" />
                        <path name="javax/validation/bootstrap" />
                        <path name="javax/validation/constraints" />
                        <path name="javax/validation/groups" />
                        <path name="javax/validation/metadata" />
                        <path name="javax/validation/spi" />
                    </exclude-set>
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which port is the management console running on when deployed on JBoss?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error or just a 404? What does the log look like when you start your app? Can you see the request mappings for the actuator's endpoints?